# SAX Parser parsing takes long time to insert in database

Tags: android, sqlite, sax

I am using SAX Parser to parse the XML file over the network. 
While parsing I want to add data into database so for that I use INSERT query to add the data. But each insert takes: 10 - 15 ms and I have almost 150 records which almost takes 130 seconds to parse and insert. 
I have tried to wrap around the insert query in transactions but it still gives me same time. I have attached my code. I am not sure if I am parsing it correctly or my insert transaction is wrong?

**XMLHandler.java**

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private static boolean inKey = false;
private static boolean inCode = false;
private static boolean inTitle = false;
private static boolean inType = false;
private static boolean inRoom = false;
private static boolean inDescription = false;
private static boolean inStart = false;

private List List = new List();

public void startElement(String uri, String name, String qName,
    Attributes atts) {

if (name.trim().equals("key"))
    inKey = true;
else if (name.trim().equals("code"))
    inCode = true;
else if (name.trim().equals("title"))
    inTitle = true;
else if (name.trim().equals("type"))
    inType = true;
else if (name.trim().equals("room"))
    inRoom = true;
else if (name.trim().equals("description"))
    inDescription = true;
else if (name.trim().equals("start"))
    inClassStart = true;

}

public void endElement(String uri, String name, String qName)
    throws SAXException {

if (name.trim().equals("key"))
    inKey = false;
else if (name.trim().equals("code"))
    inCode = false;
else if (name.trim().equals("title"))
    inTitle = false;
else if (name.trim().equals("type"))
    inType = false;
else if (name.trim().equals("room"))
    inRoom = false;
else if (name.trim().equals("description"))
    inDescription = false;
else if (name.trim().equals("start"))
    inClassStart = false;
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {

String chars = (new String(ch).substring(start, start + length));

try {
    if(inKey)
           List.key = chars;
    if(inCode)
       List.code = chars;
    if(inTitle)
        List.title = chars;
    if(inType)
        List.type = chars;
    if(inRoom)
        List.room = chars;
    if(inDescription)
        List.description = chars;
    if(inStart)
        List.start = chars;

    DB.insertFeed(List.key, List.code, List.title, List.type, List.room, List.description, List.start);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("NewsDroid", e.toString());
}

}
```

**DatabaseManager.java**

```
 public void insertFeed( String key, String code, String title, String type, String room, String desc,String start) {


    db.beginTransaction();
        try{
            String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " + TEST+  "(KEY,CODE,TITLE, TYPE ,ROOM , DESCRIPTION, START) VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
             Object [] bindArgs = new Object[]{key,code,title,type,room, desc,start};
          db.execSQL(sql, bindArgs);    
             db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
    catch (SQLException e){}

    finally{

        db.endTransaction();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inserting one row each time and might be doing db.open() and db.close() each time.
Instead of this try to use the "InsertHelper".
A crude example to use it shown below:
*`private void insertTweetSourcesInBulk(ArrayList tweetSources, boolean replace) {
        InsertHelper ih = new InsertHelper(db, TABLE_NAME_TWEET_SOURCE);`*

```
    final int idIndex = ih.getColumnIndex(Audio._ID);
    final int sequenceNumIndex = ih.getColumnIndex(TweetSource.SEQUENCE_NUM);
    final int thumbnailUrlIndex = ih.getColumnIndex(TweetSource.THUMBNAIL_URL);
    final int titleIndex = ih.getColumnIndex(TweetSource.TITLE);

    for (TweetSource source : tweetSources) {
        Logger.log(TAG, "Inserting id: " + source.getId());

        if (replace) {
            ih.prepareForReplace();
        } else {
            ih.prepareForInsert();
        }

        ih.bind(idIndex, Integer.parseInt(source.getId()));
        ih.bind(sequenceNumIndex, Float.parseFloat(source.getSequenceNum()));
        ih.bind(thumbnailUrlIndex, source.getThumbnailUrl());
        ih.bind(titleIndex, source.getTitle());

        ih.execute();
    }

    ih.close();
}
```

Comment: But then adding the strings individually while parsing in ArrayList will also take time right ?

Comment: yes but this approach is surely gonna save some time for you as it inserts more than one records in the db at same time. Also if you can have your response in JSON format, you can speed up your parsing using GSON or JACKSON parsers (I prefer jackson).

Comment: is it possible if you can explain me more how you adding ih.bind(idIndex, Integer.parseInt(source.getId())); meaning what is getId() function and what does it do ?

Answer (score 1):

Your insert statements look right. Does your database have a proper index? Because each INSERT statement has an implicit query for the existing rows since it has to determine whether a row already exists or not. If "key" on your code is indeed the primary key, then it has an implicit index, but if that's not the case... then this may cause you trouble.

Also, you should be aware that database operations are slow by nature. One thing I don't get is that if each INSERT is taking you 15ms, how come 150 INSERTs are taking 130 seconds?

Also, be sure to look at akkilis' response below (about InsertHelper) which allows you to insert several rows into your DB at once [and if that's useful to you be sure to upvote]. This will require you to accumulate your rows in a temporary buffer before feeding them into the database, which should not be very difficult.

More info on InsertHelper:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html

Comment: will definitely try that part now !! because the way I am inserting right now is crazy. It takes lot of time !

Answer (score 0):

Do not do one transaction per INSERT. Do one transaction for the entire set of INSERTs. Each transaction involves flash I/O, which is slow.